# What is the standard cost for the illustration on a Yu-Gi-Oh! card?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

The illustration on Yu-Gi-Oh! cards sometimes appeats so surrealist. I wonder how much it costs for only one image that was drawn by some artist like that, for example (these are some that crossed my mind, there is more detailed like in Zexal, ARC V, or Vrains)

[image: Book of Moon] [image: Pandemonium]

They are so detailed and there are many more detailed than this.

I found places where artists do things like draw and sell their works online. When I ask artists who interest with their work, the prices shock me, it costs like $50-$70 (we have to pay more for adding environment, background, detailed skin, colored-draw) so the total, approximately $100.

What's the actual prices of the art on Yu-Gi-Oh! card?

Comment: I think there's no correlation between commission price and the real price. I mean, they could be working officially as *Yu-Gi-Oh*'s card illustrator that got paid regularly instead of per-card based.

Comment: Is this question about how much it cost Konami to produce the artwork, or how much it would cost an individual to buy a print of it? The former is answerable on this site, since it's about game design. The latter isn't, since it's a shopping question, which is off-topic.

Comment: @Thunderforge this question is about how much it cost Konami to produce the artwork, since for each card, with a detailed illustration it must be cost a hundreds, or thousand dollar. While Konami always regularly printed a  new Card yugioh each month or years.

Answer (score 5):

[It looks like](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/5s93uc/who_exactly_are_the_artists_who_create_the_card/) the company that makes Yugioh is very tight lipped about their contracts with their artists.

[More](https://www.format.com/magazine/resources/illustration/who-pays-illustration-jobs) is known about Magic the Gathering artists, they reportedly get paid roughly $400-$600 / card, with "known" artists making more, possibly 2-3 X.

My guess would be that Yugioh artists make less than Magic the Gathering artists.

Comment: what's make you think that they got pad less ? i mean, in that reddit link you gave never stated, well i am not sure either

Comment: Magic the Gathering by revenue is significantly higher than Yugioh, consequently, I expect they pay their artists more.

Comment: And the quality of art/quality standards in general are much higher for MTG than YGO. Compare some of their most recent cards [Y1](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire_Familiar)  [M1](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443000) [Y2](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Mirror_Force) [M2](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442955) [Y3](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Scapegoat) [M3](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443023) - note that all those MTG cards are commons.

Comment: @John it seems like heartstone artwork or shadowverse

Comment: @Samthere those cards are by no means recent... Scapegoat and Mirror Force are mearly 2 decades old.

Comment: @WeckarE. Are they still using the same art on current printings? I was looking through cards from recent sets. Is there a list of only new cards I can compare to?

Comment: @Samthere Card art rarely changes for reprintings, usually only for promo cards. Unfortunately there is not really a good repo of true new cards available, but the yugioh wiki does list for every card every set they appeared in - including date of release. The newest archetypes include Sky Striker, Crusadia and Fur Hire.

Comment: @WeckarE. Right! I spent a long time trying to figure out when Vampire Familiar was originally from and getting nowhere :P That one is new from Dark Saviors, then, but the other two are much older?

Comment: YGO/MTG art comparison updated to correctly show recent cards: [Y1](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire_Familiar) vs [M1](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443000); [Y2](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Contact_Gate) vs [M2](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442955); [Y3](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Crusadia_Leonis) vs [M3](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443023). The (current) MTG art style is more consistent and detail-intensive.

Comment: @Samthere Good update! I would like to make a final note that YGO DOES purposely use different art styles to differentiate different archetypes, so consistency is naturally going to be lower.

Answer (score 3):

As John said, it is not much clear about the costs of designing a YuGiOh! card.

Yu-Gi-Oh cards don't even have flavour text (except Normal monsters), and they also don't have the artist's name on the card as several other TCG's do (like MTG, Legend of the Five Rings, etc.).

Another interesting thing to consider is that there are a few [fan-made cards](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Fan-Made_Cards), which have actually made it to real cards printed. In this case, the drawings were made by Duelists during drawing contests.

There is also the well-known [Tyler the Great Warrior](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Tyler_the_Great_Warrior), which is a card that was made because of the [Make-A-Wish foundation](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Make-A-Wish_Foundation_promotional_card), who granted Tyler Gressle his wish by creating this card in his honor.